# How to get the latest 2 records of a ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I understand that it can be a repetitive question but please can anyone help me form a query to get the latest 2 records for any particular ID . StartTime and EndTime here are UnixTimestamps here. EndTime can be 0 or NULL based on the status in general.

```
ID  StartTime   EndTime  Status
1   1000        1003     Closed
1   1003        1005     Closed
2   1002        1008     Closed
2   1008        1009     Closed
3   1002        1005     Closed
3   1005        1010     Closed
4   1006        0        Open    
2   1009        1012     Closed
1   1005        1008     Closed
3   1010        0        Open
```

Output

```
ID StartTime  EndTime Status
1  1003       1005    Closed
1  1005       1008    Closed
2  1008       1009    Closed
2  1009       1012    Closed
3  1005       1010    Closed
3  1010       0       Open
4  1006       0       Open
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select t.*,
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by starttime desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2;
```

Use `dense_rank()` if there are multiple rows on a given date, and you want two dates.

Comment: Thank you Gordon. That answer helps. Is there a way to get the top 2 days of the latest date for an id rather than the top 2 rows?

Comment: Found it. Would need to use  DENSE_RANK() instead.